# Setting values in hbm.xml files from a properties file

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

Is it possible to set values in a hibernate.hbm.xml file from a properties file??

```
<class name="com.company.table" table="TABLE" schema="$PROP_VALUE">
    <id name="id" type="integer">
        <column name="ID"/>
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="description" type="string">
        <column name="DESC" length="100" />
    </property>
</class>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying keep the schema configurable. One  option would be to configure this schema as a part of JDBC parameter configuration (in JDBC URL) instead of doing this in every entity definition. Please note tha this will not work if you are *referring to different schemas at the same time*. Not sure if this is your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the hibernate.cfg file at execution time, based on your properties file

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of, but if you are using maven you can achieve something similar using the [resource plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)